# Overflow issue with burger menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how to create burger menus for the mobile version of the site. I've managed to create a simple burger-menu with a little help of js, but I faced the problem with overflow. Burger works fine, but it has a sidescroll when it's unactive. I understand that it could be fixed with position: relative and overflow: hidden, but I can't figure out to which block I should apply those parameters. When I try to apply this parameters to the parent header block, burger menu becomes the header's hight. Can't really understand how to avoid it.

HTML:

```
`<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container">
    <a href="#"
      ><div class="logo__block">
        <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" /></div
    ></a>
    <nav class="header__nav nav">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <div class="burger-menu__exit">X</div>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Blog</a>
        </li class="nav__item nav-btn">
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="header-btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
    <div class="burger-menu">
        <div class="line line1"></div>
        <div class="line line2"></div>
        <div class="line line3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>`
```

CSS:

```
`body {
  font-family: "Libre Franklin", sans-serif;
}

[class$="__container"] {
  max-width: 1270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.header__container:before{
    position: relative;
}

.logo__block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nat__item {
}

.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav__list > li:not(.nav__item:last-child) {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.nav__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 79px;
}

.nav__link {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.btn__block {
  max-width: 286px;
}

.header-btn {
  width: 211px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff7143;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.header-btn:hover {
  background-color: #d1542b;
}

.burger-menu {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-menu__exit {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.line1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1309px) {
  [class$="__container"] {
    max-width: 1103px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1129px) {
  [class$="__container"] {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }

  .nav__list > li:not(.nav__item:last-child) {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .nav__item:last-child {
    margin-right: 79px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 988.98px) {
  [class$="__container"] {
    max-width: none;
  }

  .burger-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  .header__nav {
    background-color: #5454d4;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    z-index: 999;
    min-width: 375px;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: #ff7143;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  .nav__list {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav__list a {
    color: #ff7143;
  }

  .nav__list a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff7143;
  }

  .nav__list > li:not(.nav__item:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .nav__item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .header-btn {
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  .burger-menu__exit {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 18px;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 512.98px) {
  .header-btn {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 369.98px) {
  .nav {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}`
```

JS:

```
    const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".nav");
const headerButton = document.querySelector(".header-btn");
const headerContainer = document.querySelector(".header__container");

document.querySelector(".burger-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
  mobileNav.style.right = 0;
});

document.querySelector(".burger-menu__exit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  mobileNav.style.right = -100 + "%";
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please paste your code here instead of providing `codepen` link.

Comment: replaced the codepen link with the code, you can check it above

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by adding the different navigation for burger outside the header block and adding the `position: relative; overflow: hidden;` to the html and body.